# I'd like to know if this is a grammatically correct sentence. "I determined to go back to college."

Tags: grammar, verbs, adjectives

I know that I can say, *I was determined to go back to college.*, And also that I can use a synonym, but I'd like to know if the above is correct and why/why not. I feel like one is an intent and one a decision, don't ask me why....

Comment: They are related. See sense 3 of [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/determine).

Comment: Thank you. I did look myself, but was unable to find a definitive answer. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

"I determined to go back to college" is perfectly correct English. It means something different from "I was determined to go back to college."

[The verb "determine" (past participle *determined*) means "to come to a decision"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/determine?s=t), so your titular sentence means you have decided to go to college, rather than being resolute about going to college, which is what the adjective *determined* means.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, I'm writing a scholarship essay, and I'd much rather hear it from you guys than trust internet opinions!

Comment: Thanks, but don't forget, we *are* internet opinions. We like to think we are good ones, but still internet opinions.